# Why mean in Gaussian Process is not so important?

Tags: regression, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process

Source of my doubt is the section 2.7 of [GPML book by Rasmussen](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf), an screenshot of the book is attached below. Much of my confusion is clarified by [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222238/why-is-the-mean-function-in-gaussian-process-uninteresting).

If mean of GP is not estimated and it is taken as zero or any constant, then outside the range of the observations the estimate would converge to 0/constant. But suppose if I am interested in prediction within the domain of training data.

What would happen if I vary the mean of GP? Would the parameters of covariance function tune themselves accordingly?

[image]